# User Interface in Prolog

Tags: user-interface, prolog

I have been begun programming in Prolog lately and find the language very dry. Is there a way by which, after having built the database of facts and rules, we can interface that with a webpage written in PHP or any other language So that the query is triggered from the webpage and after the response has been known it is given back to the webpage.

Comment: This is not a matter of language, but of library, and dialects differ. Which Prolog?

Comment: Worst case, you could probably write input files from the webby-friendly language and run the prolog environment directly... but that's a bit ugly. More details on your environment might allow for better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use ECLiPSe as your Prolog system, then you can use Andrea Montemaggio's [communication layer between PHP and ECliPSe-CLP](https://code.google.com/p/php-eclipseclp/). Or you can write your own http server using ECLiPSe's [http-server library](http://www.eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/http_server/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SWI-Prolog HTTP support](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/package/http.html); might come in handy.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I think the link from Roman helped a lot. Thank you for your answers.